# How do I browse folder using simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I want to add a file/folder browsing button in my rails application using `simple_form` gem.
How do I do it? In simple_form documentation it is not mentioned.

Edit: File browse is mentioned in the documentation. But how to browse folders is not mentioned. Currently the only way I think possible is extract the folder from the file path. But what if there are no files present in the folder?

Comment: It's right there in the documentation https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type

Comment: @Deepak: Yes file I noticed after you mentioned. But folder is missing. Currently I have to have some file in the directory from the file path I extract the directory path. Is there any easier way?

Comment: I think everyone reading this question is a little confused about what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to allow the user to upload an entire folder of files?

Comment: @ChrisPeters: No, User selects a folder and I will dump a file into that folder. But folder selection is not found in simple_form documentation. It has file method. But if I don't have any file in target folder, I can't select that folder.

Comment: I think that you're having a lot of trouble because what you're trying to accomplish is not possible with an HTML `input` element.

Comment: @ChrisPeters: What is the solution? Any alternative?

Comment: The most common solution is to provide a download link with instructions to right-click and "Save as...." Another is to have your server respond with headers that force the user to pick a folder and download a file. You could also possibly author a browser plugin that your users must install before using your web app. You'd need to do that for each browser because their APIs may be a little different. (I've never done that before however.) This 3rd solution is not realistic in my opinion if you want for your users to actually like you.

Comment: I must also add that the server headers don't necessarily force the user to pick a folder. Some browsers may just instantly dump the file into their default download folder.

Comment: @ChrisPeters: Why is browsing a file allowed but folder?

Comment: The point of a file input is to pick a file to upload to the server, not to pick a destination for downloads. You can't "upload" a folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do:

```
f.input :somename, as: :file
```

Comment: Hi, I want to know how to browse a folder as well. For example if the directory is empty I can't select it with as: :file